# Javascript array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

We have a two by three array.Which means two rows three columns.Somwhere in the code  I came accross this

```
var t = new Array( 2 );

t[ 0 ] = new Array( 3 )
t[ 1 ] = new Array( 3 );
```

t[0] is an element,right? In the zero position.

So this means that we create an element in the zeroeth position in the array of three elements? Or that we create said element in the array of three columns? How will the computer know 3 means 3 columns?

Comment: Computer actually doesn't know about columns. It just sees some nested arrays.

Comment: MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax Read arrayLength

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no multi dimensional arrays in Javascript, so you always use arrays of arrays (jagged arrays) for that.

When you create a jagged array you first create the outer array. Then you create an inner array for each item in the outer array.

In your example `t[0]` is the first item in the outer array, it's assigned the inner array.

Another way to create a jagged array is to use array literals, which may help visualise what they really look like:

```
var t = [
  [ 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0 ]
];
```

Comment: Looks like a matrix to me

Comment: @KamiH: Yes, it does, but note that `var t = [ ... ];` is one array and each `[ 0, 0, 0 ]` inside it is one array.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the Array constructor with a number gives you an array initialized with its `length` property set to that number. It doesn't mean "3 columns" therefore; it just means an array whose length is 3.

JavaScript does not have real multi-dimensional arrays like C or FORTRAN do. An array is always a one-dimensional list of values. You can, however, put an array in a cell of another array, and that's what your code does. This:

```
var t = new Array(2);
```

creates an array whose length is 2.  Then, the next two lines:

```
t[ 0 ] = new Array( 3 );
t[ 1 ] = new Array( 3 );
```

put new arrays of length 3 in each of the two cells of that array. It's now possible to use that assembly as if it were a real 2-dimensional array.

Note that what I mean by "real 2-dimensional array" is an array allocated as a single block of raw storage, row by row or column by column depending on the programming language. The distinction is important mostly for performance reasons, but flexibility is another consideration. It's possible in JavaScript to have an array of arrays such that the rows are not all the same length.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to know how many elements are in your jagged array, you can try t.length and t[0].length to find out. Like others already mentioned above, it's better to create an array with [ ] and elements can be defined in it or use push method to insert each element to it.